# Annotation for UDT by Spring data Cassandra

Tags: user-defined-types, spring-data-cassandra

How does springdatacassandra support user defined data types provided by Cassandra in POJO? I am looking for annotation for UDT.

Comment: similar question is here with the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862460/user-defined-type-with-spring-data-cassandra/42036202#42036202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring data cassandra latest version (1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) depends on datastax driver 2.0.4 , where as UDT is supported since datastax driver 2.1.x.

You can try overriding the datastax driver to 2.1.x to consume the latest features provided by the 2.1 driver.

Comment: Thanku @shatk for the reply. this is what i was looking for.

Comment: Just to make it clearer : `@UDT` and other mapping annotations (`com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.*`) seen in the DataStax docs are NOT supported by spring-data-cassandra to this point. These annotations are provided by the artifact `cassandra-driver-mapping`. Classes annotated with DataStax's annotations need to be persisted through a `com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper`, see http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/mappingUdts.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

is needed, but in total it will not work, spring data cassandra does not support UDT mapping.

See the details here:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-172

I faced with this issue and debug process showed me that spring data cassandra check  for
@Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation only and raises the  exception in another case

> >
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.VerifierMappingExceptions:
>   Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation

But I found the solution.
I figured out the approach that allows me to manage entities that include UDT and the ones that don't. In my application I use spring cassandra data project together with using of direct datastax core driver. The repositories that don't contain object with UDT use spring cassanta data approach and the objects that include UDT use custom repositories.
Custom repositories use datastax mapper and they work correctly with UDT
(they located in separate package, see notes below why it's needed):

```
package com.fyb.cassandra.custom.repositories.impl;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean;

import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.Result;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.fyb.cassandra.custom.repositories.AccountDeviceRepository;
import com.fyb.cassandra.dto.AccountDevice;

public class AccountDeviceRepositoryImpl implements AccountDeviceRepository {

    @Autowired
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session;

    private Mapper<AccountDevice> mapper;

    @PostConstruct
    void initialize() {
        mapper = new MappingManager(session.getObject()).mapper(AccountDevice.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<AccountDevice> findAll() {
        return fetchByQuery("SELECT * FROM account_devices");
    }

    @Override
    public void save(AccountDevice accountDevice) {
        mapper.save(accountDevice);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteByConditions(UUID accountId, UUID systemId, UUID deviceId) {
        final String query = "DELETE FROM account_devices where account_id =" + accountId + " AND system_id=" + systemId
                + " AND device_id=" + deviceId;
        session.getObject().execute(query);
    }

    @Override
    public List<AccountDevice> findByAccountId(UUID accountId) {
        final String query = "SELECT * FROM account_devices where account_id=" + accountId;
        return fetchByQuery(query);
    }

    /*
     * Take any valid CQL query and try to map result set to the given list of appropriates <T> types.
     */
    private List<AccountDevice> fetchByQuery(String query) {
        ResultSet results = session.getObject().execute(query);
        Result<AccountDevice> accountsDevices = mapper.map(results);
        List<AccountDevice> result = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (AccountDevice accountsDevice : accountsDevices) {
            result.add(accountsDevice);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the spring data related repos that resonsible for managing entities that don't include UDT objects looks like as follows:

```
package com.fyb.cassandra.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;

import com.fyb.cassandra.dto.AccountUser;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface AccountUserRepository extends CassandraRepository<AccountUser> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account_users WHERE account_id=?0")
    List<AccountUser> findByAccountId(UUID accountId);
}
```

I've tested this solution and it's works 100%.
In addition I've attached my  POJO objects:

Pojo that uses only data stax annatation:

```
package com.fyb.cassandra.dto;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.ClusteringColumn;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Column;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Frozen;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.FrozenValue;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.PartitionKey;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;

@Table(name = "account_systems")
public class AccountSystem {

    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private java.util.UUID accountId;

    @ClusteringColumn
    @Column(name = "system_id")
    private java.util.UUID systemId;

    @Frozen
    private Location location;

    @FrozenValue
    @Column(name = "user_token")
    private List<UserToken> userToken;

    @Column(name = "product_type_id")
    private int productTypeId;

    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private String serialNumber;   
}
```

Pojo without using UDT and using only spring data cassandra framework:

```
package com.fyb.cassandra.dto;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

@Table(value = "accounts")
public class Account {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "account_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private java.util.UUID accountId;

    @Column(value = "account_name")
    private String accountName;

    @Column(value = "currency")
    private String currency;    
}
```

Note, that the entities below use different annotations:

```
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "account_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)and @PartitionKey
@ClusteringColumn and @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "area_parent_id", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
```

At first glance - it's uncomfortable, but it allows you to work with objects that includes UDT and that don't.

One important note. That two repos(that use UDT and don't should reside in different packages) cause Spring config looking for base packages with repos:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {
        "com.fyb.cassandra.repositories" })
public class CassandraConfig {
..........
}
```