# How map UDT (User defined type) in Spring-Data-Cassandara

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using Spring-data-cassandra 1.5.0M1.
I can't find a way to map custom/UDT types in my POJO.
Also I saw this post [Annotation for UDT by Spring data Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813696/annotation-for-udt-by-spring-data-cassandra). But I hope that in new version is added support for UDT types.
For example I have Message UDT in my Cassandra 3.7 DB

```
CREATE TYPE MESSAGE (reply TEXT, time TIMESTAMP, user TEXT, patient UUID, status INT);
```

How can I map it in my entity POJO class like this?

```
@Table("conversations")
```

public class Conversation {

```
@org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey
private PrimaryKey primaryKey = new PrimaryKey();

@Column("status")
private Integer conversationStatus;

@Column("last_update")
private Date lastUpdate;

@Column("name")
private String name;

@Column("messages")
private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

public UUID getId() {
    return primaryKey.id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    primaryKey.id = id;
}

public Integer getConversationStatus() {
    return conversationStatus;
}

public void setConversationStatus(Integer conversationStatus) {
    this.conversationStatus = conversationStatus;
}

public Date getLastUpdate() {
    return lastUpdate;
}

public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Message> getMessages() {
    return messages;
}

public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Conversation rhs = (Conversation) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder()
            .append(this.primaryKey.id, rhs.primaryKey.id)
            .append(this.conversationStatus, rhs.conversationStatus)
            .append(this.lastUpdate, rhs.lastUpdate)
            .append(this.name, rhs.name)
            .append(this.messages, rhs.messages)
            .isEquals();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder()
            .append(primaryKey)
            .append(conversationStatus)
            .append(lastUpdate)
            .append(name)
            .append(messages)
            .toHashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this)
            .append("primaryKey", primaryKey)
            .append("conversationStatus", conversationStatus)
            .append("lastUpdate", lastUpdate)
            .append("name", name)
            .append("messages", messages)
            .toString();
}

public static final class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4188262171705712608L;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private UUID id;

    public PrimaryKey() {
    }

    public PrimaryKey(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final PrimaryKey rhs = (PrimaryKey) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(this.id, rhs.id)
                .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder()
                .append(id)
                .toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this)
                .append("id", id)
                .toString();
    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not supported with 1.5.0.M1 but will come with a M2 or RC1 release. We have an open PR to support UDT mapping by using `@UserDefinedType`, check out https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/84

Comment: Do you know when will be the release of M2 or RC1?

Comment: Expect Ingalls RC1 end of November (https://spring-calendar.cfapps.io/)

Comment: see answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862460/user-defined-type-with-spring-data-cassandra?noredirect=1&lq=1